# Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 - last screen flashes when waking up

Tags: gnome, lock-screen, 15.10

I recently upgraded 15.04 to 15.10, and then I started to see my last desktop screen flashes before the lockscreen shows up when I open my laptop. 
Might not be a big trouble, but I'm little bit concerned about a privacy issue.

Is anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: Yep, same here but with Unity.
Seems to be related to Ubuntu 15 rather than Gnome/Unity.

Comment: Me too. 15.10 fresh install, Dell XPS 13 (L421X).

Comment: I get this too on a Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro and it annoys me every time. There's an open bug on this, looks like it's new to Wily: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1504362